# refreshing materialized views in quill

Tags: scala, quill, materialized-views

how do I execute queries  that looks like this using scala Quill library?

`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY transaction_view`

Answer (score 0):

Basically this can be archived by writing it in a quote

```
val q = quote { query[MyTable] }
val myQuery = quote { infix"REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY {$q}".as[Query[MyTable]] }
```

Thanks to @deusaquilus

Answer (score 0):

The answer from binkabir is *almost* correct. One last touch needed is to replace Query with Action, otherwise Quill will again generate a select, instead of just using the raw string.

```
val q = quote { query[MyTable] }
val myQuery = quote { infix"REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY {$q}".as[Action[MyTable]] }
```